# How to get values from a form on a webpage using jsoup in android?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I am using jsoup for webpage parsing. I want to get the value of a specific input field, like `Hamza` for the case shown below. How can I do that using jsoup?

```
<li>
  <label for="borrower_surname" class="required">
    Surname:
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="borrower_surname" name="borrower_surname" value="Hamza" />
  <span class="required">
    Required
  </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

Just use the attribute selector [`attrname=attrvalue`].

```
public  class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s ="<li>\n" +
                "  <label for=\"borrower_surname\" class=\"required\">\n" +
                "    Surname:\n" +
                "  </label>\n" +
                "  <input type=\"text\" id=\"borrower_surname\" name=\"borrower_surname\" value=\"Hamza\" />\n" +
                "  <span class=\"required\">\n" +
                "    Required\n" +
                "  </span>\n" +
                "</li>";
        Document document= Jsoup.parse(s);
        Element element = document.select("input[name=borrower_surname]").first();
        String inputValue = element.attr("value");
        System.out.println(inputValue);
    }
    }
```